# Как вывести все комбинации покупок за заданную сумму?

Tags: python, комбинаторика

До меня не доходит как эту задачу решить

Вкратце: у фермера есть 100 т.р., он хочет купить скот. Какого количества и какого скота он может купить на эти деньги?
Стоимость: бык 10 т.р., корова 5 т.р., теленок 500 руб.

Вариантов тут масса. Я не понимаю как вывести их все. Например, он может купить 9 быков, 1 корову и 10 телят. Как это вывести в принт?

Я сделал так. Но это выводит только 3 из возможных вариантов:

```
b = 10000  # бык
k = 5000  # корова
t = 500  # теленок
s = 100000  # общая сумма


def prog(x, y, i, z):
    return x / y, x / i, x / z


print(prog(s, b, k, t))
```

Но это явно что-то не то...

Comment: А точно надо вывести все варианты?...

Comment: Да, тоже это уточняли)

Comment: Попахивает рекурсией ;-)

Comment: @Kromster Циклом...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так сойдет?

```
b = 10000   # бык
k = 5000    # корова
t = 500     # теленок
s = 100000  # общая сумма

for ib in range(0,s//b+1):
    ns = s - ib * b
    for ik in range(0,ns//k+1):
        nns = ns - ik * k
        it = nns//t
        print("Быки: ", ib, " Коровы: ", ik, " Телята: ", it)
```

Comment: Это не верно:) Бык нужен всегда один, коров побольше, остальное - телята:))))))

Comment: @Виктор Экий вы не толерантный :)

Answer (score -1):

```
b = 10000  # бык
k = 5000  # корова
t = 500  # теленок
s = 100000  # общая сумма

print(f"Быков: {s/b}, Коров: {s/k}, Телят: {s/t}")
```

Как-то так

Comment: Тут ключевое понятие - комбинаторика - *"Например, он может купить 9 быков, 1 корову и 10 телят"*